# How to get every possible string of n characters in c++?

Tags: c++, string, permutation

I know it is possible to use n nested for loops to get the result. This however isn't very flexible. If I wanted to get every string of n+2 characters I would have to write an extra two for loops.

I'm pretty sure I should use a parameter called n_Letters and use some kind of recursion. Any ideas? This is how my code looks right now. It gives all the 3 character combinations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void StringMaker(){
   for(int firstLetter = 97; firstLetter < 123; firstLetter++){
    char a = firstLetter;
    for(int secondLetter = 97; secondLetter < 123; secondLetter++){
        char b = secondLetter;
        for(int thirdLetter = 97; thirdLetter < 123; thirdLetter++){
            char c = thirdLetter;
            cout << a << b << c << endl;
        }
    }
}
}

int main() {
    StringMaker(); // I could add a parameter n_Letters here
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you return a `string` from `StringMaker`.

Comment: That's true. I will edit it to void.

Comment: You should use `'a'` and `'z'` instead `97` and `123`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, that's debatable. If you rely on a certain ordering of the characters' corresponding numeric values, then why not use the values directly?

Comment: Oh! I wrote code for this _exact_ purpose! http://ideone.com/UpwKvC

Comment: You already figured out you need recursion, why don't you try it?

Comment: The function should take a parameter `n_Letters `. It does one for loop over all characters, and in each iteration it calls itself (recursively) with `n_Letters - 1`.

Comment: @DonReba Using the appropriate constants makes the code significantly easier to understand. That's one of the purposes of a constant.

Comment: @smead I have tried it. I'm new to programming and I always have big troubles with recursion so I asked for help.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, both `97` and `'a'` are literals, not constants.

Comment: Well, post the code you've tried. All you've really done is asked for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: @DonReba literals are constants

Comment: OP, is this a homework assignment by any chance? If so, please mark it with the 'homework' tag.

Comment: It's not. Our school site has a hack achievement and a friend and I are very close to getting it. We found out which commands to use but it just needs the right string to complete it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple tree traversal problem that can easily be solved using recursion. Using a counter (`count`) and accumulator (`partial`) recur on your function for each letter until `count` is zero then print `partial`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void StringMaker(int count, std::string partial = "") {
    if (count == 0) {
        std::cout << partial << '\n';
    }
    else {
        for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; ++letter) {
            StringMaker(count - 1, partial + letter);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    StringMaker(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: It seems their are some concerns with my answer regarding memory allocations. If it's a concern for you, consider this alternative solution. Increment the first character if it isn't `'z'`, otherwise set it to `a` and repeat with the the second character. Do this until the last character is set from `z` to `a`. This acts as a sort of base 26 counter with `count` digits.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void StringMaker(size_t count) 
{
    std::string data(count, 'a');
    size_t i = 0;
    do
    {
        std::cout << data << '\n';

        for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            auto & next_char = data[i];
            if (next_char < 'z') {
                ++next_char;
                break;
            }
            else {
                next_char = 'a';
            }
        }

    } while (i != count);
}

int main() {
    StringMaker(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I started with c++ yesterday and hadn't heard about an accumulator before. I will definitely look into it more. I also didn't know that you could simply use 'a' instead of 97. Thanks :)

Comment: The first solution was tested on a platform with short string optimization. It will likely not hold up for longer strings, or on systems without that optimization. I would remove it, but I would rather not dramatically alter an answer after it's been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my just-for-fun solution:

```
void StringMaker(int n)
{
      int base = ('z' - 'a' + 1);
      std::string str(n, '\0');

      for(int i = 0; i < int_pow(base, n); ++i)
      {
            for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            {
                  str[n - j - 1] = 'a' + i / int_pow(base, j) % base;
            }
            cout << str << '\n';
      }
}
```

Suppose we have `i` written in numerical system with base 26 (from a to z), so increment i with n = 4 give us aaaa, aaab and so on